# Instability of pandas dataframe calculations

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm wondering whether anyone has seen this problem with Pandas before.  Basically, I'm trying to add, multiply, and divide DataFrames element-by-element (all the frames have identical indexes and columns), but Pandas is spitting out different results for the same calculation performed successively.

An image of some example output is shown below.  I've used `.values` in the code below because for display purposes, but the instability can happen when using `.add()`, `.mul()`, or `.div()`.  For example, if I repeatedly enter `N11.add(N00)`, I usually get the correct answer, but occasionally (every 4th or 5th time), I get a DataFrame filled with 0s.

[image]

If it matters, I'm on Windows 10 using an Anaconda distribution of Pandas 0.17.0 (with Python 2.7.10 on Spyder 2.3.7).  The frames that I am working with are large (6856 by 12511).  Has anyone else encountered this problem?  Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Interesting - any chance you could reproduce the behaviour with smaller DataFrames and post them as part of the question here?

Comment: (Also if you're just multiplying NumPy arrays this might be a NumPy issue.)

Comment: Okay, well I tried it with a smaller 10x10 frame, and couldn't reproduce it after almost 100 tries.  So maybe size does matter here.

Comment: That is very odd indeed, because the real values are nowhere near zero.  Tough to debug without a reproducible example though.

Comment: If you make a temporary variable like `tmp = (N11+N00+N01+N10).values` and then do `tmp*tmp` repeatedly, does the error ever occur?  I wonder if it is due to some sort of timing quirk because you're accessing the same `.values` twice in the same expression, possibly causing an interaction with the garbage collector or something.

Comment: Good idea BrenBarn.  So I just tried it now, and strangely enough my first assignment of `tmp` (`tmp = (N11+N00+N10+N01).values`) came out as all zeros, so I had to re-enter the line, which produced the correct values.  From there, I was able to call `tmp*tmp` or `tmp+tmp` with no issues after about 50 calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue today and it was caused by [a bug in numexpr 2.4.4](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/issues/185). It seems to be biting other pandas users in various ways, as reported in [this pandas ticket](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12023) and others linked to it.

Upgrading numexpr to 2.4.6 solved the problem for us, but it looks like any version that's not 2.4.4 should be fine!

Comment: Thanks mactyr!  That seemed to fix it.  For some strange reason, the problem went away on its own for a while.  I reinstalled Anaconda several times during that period for unrelated reasons, so I thought the fix might be due to the reinstalls.  Then suddenly, yesterday a Windows update got pushed onto me, and everything was breaking again.  I updated numexpr to v2.5 and now everything is back to normal.  What a strange bug!

Comment: @user3111891, yeah, I think there was a mention in the numexpr ticket I linked to of the problem being Windows-specific; it could be linked to specific updates or just something about the overall state the system is in. Since you seem to agree that this answer solves the problem, could you mark it as accepted? I'm not a big stackoverflow user but it would be nice to get a little bit of rep for a job well done! :)(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Hi mactyr, yes, sorry, I was trying to do that, but in my stackoverflow ignorance, I tried clicking the up arrow, which was rejected by the site because I'm too newbie myself.  I see the check now and I'm happy to give you the grand prize (congrats!) and thanks for sharing!